# What exactly happens here?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

```
for (int i = 7; i >= 0;i--) {
    cout << ((c >> i) & 1);
```

This takes a char, c and prints out it's binary. How does this work though, specifically the second line.

Answer (score 4):

It takes the bits at positions 7 through 0 respectively, which is the bits from left to right, and for each, writes out either a 1 or a 0.  The `& 1` is used to isolate the ith bit after shifting it right `i` places.

Example:

Given char 'A', equivalent to `0x41` or `01000001` in binary:

```
010000001 >> 7 ==> 0  ==> & 1 ==> 0
010000001 >> 6 ==> 01  ==> & 1 ==> 1
010000001 >> 5 ==> 010  ==> & 1 ==> 0
010000001 >> 4 ==> 0100  ==> & 1 ==> 0
010000001 >> 3 ==> 01000  ==> & 1 ==> 0
010000001 >> 2 ==> 010000  ==> & 1 ==> 0
010000001 >> 1 ==> 0100000  ==> & 1 ==> 0
010000001 >> 0 ==> 01000001  ==> & 1 ==> 1
```

Comment: Why is it only taking 7 bit positions when a char is 1 byte (8 bits)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "taking 7"

Answer (score 1):

It is shifting the next bit from char c to the right.  Then the AND with 1 will return a result of 1 if that bit was set, or 0 if not.